# Use "Optional, DefaultParameterValue" attribute, or not?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, optional-parameters

Is there any difference between using `Optional` and `DefaultParameterValue` attributes and not using them?

```
public void Test1([Optional, DefaultParameterValue("param1")] string p1, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue("param2")] string p2)
{
}

public void Test2(string p1= "param1", string p2= "param2")
{
}
```

both work:

```
Test1(p2: "aaa");
Test2(p2: "aaa");
```

Comment: Good question, didn´t even know those attributes exist.

Comment: There is, but you are unlikely to encounter it in practice when you write code like this.  The [Optional] attribute was hijacked in C# version 4 to help write easier COM interop code.  The argument would have to be object without a default to see it, the caller then passes Type.Missing.  Using the provided syntax sugar is of course always best.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is that by using the attributes explicitly, the compiler doesn't enforce the same strictness on type requirements.

```
public class C {
  // accepted
  public void f([Optional, DefaultParameterValue(1)] object i) { }

  // error CS1763: 'i' is of type 'object'. A default parameter value of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null
  //public void g(object i = 1) { }

  // works, calls f(1)
  public void h() { f(); }
}
```

Note that even with `DefaultParameterValue`, you don't throw out type-safety: if the types are incompatible, this will still be flagged.

```
public class C {
  // error CS1908: The type of the argument to the DefaultParameterValue attribute must match the parameter type
  //public void f([Optional, DefaultParameterValue("abc")] int i) { }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

They compile identically, and the compiler works fine with either. The only difference is the lack of `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`, and easier to read code.

For reference, the IL is:

```
.method public hidebysig instance void TheName([opt] string p1,
    [opt] string p2) cil managed
{
    .param [1] = string('param1')
    .param [2] = string('param2')
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ret 
}
```

where `TheName` is the only thing that changes.

Comment: Check the answer by @hvd. While they work almost the same, the InteropServices is clearly **not their only difference**.

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace System.Runtime.InteropServices {

    using System;

    //
    // The DefaultParameterValueAttribute is used in C# to set 
    // the default value for parameters when calling methods
    // from other languages. This is particularly useful for 
    // methods defined in COM interop interfaces.
    //
    [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
    public sealed class DefaultParameterValueAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
         public DefaultParameterValueAttribute(object value)
         {
             this.value = value;
         }

         public object Value { get { return this.value; } }

         private object value;
    }
}
```

They are doing the same job. You can check things like this in [**Roslyn**](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlaIoYB0ASsBMmOqsQJKWoBOA9gA5zMBuYAxqiBxtgAIwA2fGLzEBDECBgBhGAG9sMDTGHjJXFmAAmMALIAKAJSr1mmwBUByAIwWcNuw4BML6xoC+PmADtCV4YPUMYexRnAG0AeTYqFggZMQAaGAARVAAzGWAxZAAFGSYZGjQmADVU4FRTACI2UvLHBvMAXRgUJnwtRwz4xLBk1IzsvILilormGrE6xuay9A92rp6+tg9zALUbfyDRELD9IyjkL03ofoBeGCaZtozr2G37x5W13Zt9zX9fEA=) or in [**ReferenceSource**](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/runtime/interopservices/DefaultParameterValueAttribute.cs,2fab7ee560921f9a)