# How are Optional attribute and nullable references supposed to work together?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, roslyn

I am a big fan of C# nullable references and we enable them in all our new projects. Recently I was reviewing a PR from a co-worker and found that [Optional] attribute was used next to the reference parameter with no default value being specified. This would mean that we are breaking "nullable reference constraint" as the default value for the function argument would be null, even though the argument is not marked as nullable. Please see the example code below:

```
class Program
{
    internal class Data
    {
        internal int Count { get; set; } = 3;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BadUse();
        GoodUse();
    }

    static void BadUse([Optional] Data data) => Console.WriteLine($"Data: ${data.Count}");

    static void BadUse2([Optional, DefaultParameterValue(null)] Data data) => Console.WriteLine($"Data: ${data.Count}");

    static void GoodUse(Data? data = null) => Console.WriteLine($"Data: ${data?.Count}");
}
```

As you can see the method `BadUse` above is incorrect and will cause null reference exception without any warning nor compilation error. Naturally, we use the more readable optional argument pattern as in `GoodUse`. I wonder if this is a bug in C# compiler or I am missing something here? I would expect to see compilation error or at least some warning.
Note that when the DefaultParameterValue attribute is used in `BadUse2` we get the expected "CS8602 Dereference of a possibly null reference".

Comment: probably worth raising an issue on the compiler github to get a more definitive answer  https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use "Optional, DefaultParameterValue" attribute, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171095/use-optional-defaultparametervalue-attribute-or-not)

Comment: This seems like something _extra_ they added to Microsoft's implementation of C# - not in the specification or the ECMA standard, or this could just be a consequence of the implementation detail of optional parameters. And I guess when they were implementing nullable reference types, they forgot to handle this case (?)

Comment: @NicholasHunter, Thanks I looked at it before asking and it helped me choosing which optional argument syntax to use (hint: definitely not the optional attribute). However, after looking at it one more time I have tried the DefaultParameterValue attribute and it works fine with it. Will expand example.

Comment: @KeithNicholas I created an issue and will link it once it gets triaged and put into right repo.

Comment: Related github issue: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/52792